# Romance manga where a guy tutors a girl who turns out to be a millionaire

Tags: billionaire-girl

A couple of months ago, i read a manga about a guy who get's a job to tutor a girl for math or other things, and he finds out shes a rich million air girl. She made her money by stocks, and he's curious and decides to learn stocks to get closer with her.

That's really all I know, It should be enough though. **it's a romance 90%**

Hope you can get me the name of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am sure the manga in question is [**Billionaire Girl**](http://myanimelist.net/manga/23588/Billionaire_Girl)

The guy's name is Takato Kei. He tutors this rich teenage girl for 10000 Yen per hour.

[image]

It a complete romance story. In reality she is not a high school girl who has amassed a lot of wealth from stock market. I think this covers the description you gave. Hope this helps :D

**BTW Fun-Fact:** I just noticed it was written by Isuna Hasekura (of Spice and Wolf fame :D ).

Comment: Perfect, thnx! :D